# Form for OTP entry with six single-character text fields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am working on an app in which I have to pass 6 digits OTP through 6 textFields in which you to provide only one character and after that it automatically goes to another textField. I created 6 textFields outlets and used this code. The problem I have is that I want to change the specific `textField` OTP number but the problem is that if I want to change the OTP number of textfield 4 after tapping cross button it automatically goes to the textfield 3. How can I fix this issue?

**The code I used:**

```
import UIKit

class OneTimePasswordViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP4: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP5: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP6: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        txtOTP1.delegate = self
        txtOTP2.delegate = self
        txtOTP3.delegate = self
        txtOTP4.delegate = self
        txtOTP5.delegate = self
        txtOTP6.delegate = self

       self.txtOTP1.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

And here is the code for creating logic:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if (range.length == 0){
        if textField == txtOTP1 {txtOTP2?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP2 {txtOTP3?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP3 {txtOTP4?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP4 {txtOTP5?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP5 {txtOTP6?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP6 {txtOTP6?.resignFirstResponder()}
        textField.text? = string
        return false
    }
    else if (range.length == 1) {

        if textField == txtOTP6 {txtOTP5?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP5 {txtOTP4?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP4 {txtOTP3?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP3 {txtOTP2?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP2 {txtOTP1?.becomeFirstResponder()}
        if textField == txtOTP1 {txtOTP1?.resignFirstResponder()}

        textField.text? = ""
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

[image]
 [image]

[image]

Comment: To start with, try using an Outlet Collection of `[UITextField]` there than declaring each field separately. This will cut down on a lot or repeated code

Comment: Actually Sir the problem is different I want to change the 4 textfield but when click cross button it goes to the 3 textfield i want to be there on textfield 4.

Comment: My comment isn't a solution to your problem - but it will give you code that is more concise, easier to read and to update.

Comment: okay Sir I will try that but do you know the solution of this problem?

Comment: Is this a passcode sent to your mobile device? If so, take a look at WWDC video about security code autofill… https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/

Comment: yes it is sent to mobile

Comment: In that case you should watch the video.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180347/discussion-between-v-rohit-and-ashley-mills).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try My 3rd party library:-
https://github.com/Datt1994/DPOTPView

**For Solution:-**

In viewDidLoad add tag & delegate to all `textfield`

```
import UIKit

class OneTimePasswordViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP1: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP2: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP3: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP4: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP5: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var txtOTP6: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        txtOTP1.delegate = self
        txtOTP1.tag = 1000
        txtOTP2.delegate = self
        txtOTP2.tag = 2000
        txtOTP3.delegate = self
        txtOTP3.tag = 3000
        txtOTP4.delegate = self
        txtOTP4.tag = 4000
        txtOTP5.delegate = self
        txtOTP5.tag = 5000
        txtOTP6.delegate = self
        txtOTP6.tag = 6000

       self.txtOTP1.becomeFirstResponder()
   }
}
```

In UITextFieldDelegate extension implement `shouldChangeCharactersIn` function like below, It will also work with `textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode`

```
extension OneTimePasswordViewController : UITextFieldDelegate  {

public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces).count != 0 {
        textField.text = string
        if textField.tag < count*1000 {
            let next = textField.superview?.viewWithTag((textField.tag/1000 + 1)*1000)
            next?.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if textField.tag == count*1000 {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    } else if string.count == 0 { // is backspace
        textField.text = ""
    }

    return false
}

}
```